# Differing behaviors for ParseFiles functions in html/template

Tags: go, go-templates

I don't understand why the behaviors of `func (t *Template) Parsefiles(...` differs from `func ParseFiles(...`.  Both functions are from the "html/template" package.

```
package example

import (
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "testing"
)

func MakeTemplate1(path string) *template.Template {
    return template.Must(template.ParseFiles(path))
}

func MakeTemplate2(path string) *template.Template {
    return template.Must(template.New("test").ParseFiles(path))
}

func TestExecute1(t *testing.T) {
    tmpl := MakeTemplate1("template.html")

    err := tmpl.Execute(ioutil.Discard, "content")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}

func TestExecute2(t *testing.T) {
    tmpl := MakeTemplate2("template.html")

    err := tmpl.Execute(ioutil.Discard, "content")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

This exits with the error:

```
--- FAIL: TestExecute2 (0.00 seconds)
    parse_test.go:34: html/template:test: "test" is an incomplete or empty template
FAIL
exit status 1
```

Note that `TestExecute1` passed fine so this not a problem with `template.html`.

What's going on here?
What am I missing in `MakeTemplate2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because of the template names. `Template` objects can hold multiple teplates, each has a name. When using `template.New("test")`, and then Executing it, it will try to execute a template called `"test"` inside that template. However, `tmpl.ParseFiles` stores the template to the name of the file. That explains the error message.

How to fix it:

a) Give the template the correct name:
Use

```
return template.Must(template.New("template.html").ParseFiles(path))
```

instead of

```
return template.Must(template.New("test").ParseFiles(path))
```

b) Specify, which template you want to execute in you `Template` object:
Use

```
err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(ioutil.Discard, "template.html", "content")
```

instead of

```
err := tmpl.Execute(ioutil.Discard, "content")
```

Read more about this in http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: So why does `TestExecute1` work correctly?  If I understand you, it will be given the implicit name of `template.html`.  But I don't use `ExecuteTemplate` and it works fine.

Comment: exactly, the name `template.html` will be given implicitly, so it executes the right template in the object.